# Javascript variable not setting correctly

Tags: javascript

I have the following code where I need to set the "status" variable depending on the success or failure of an ajax call.

```
function loadPMMLAvailability(algorithmName) {
    var status = false;
    if (algorithmName) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: serverUrl + '/api/configs/pmml/' + algorithmName,
            success: function (res) {
                status = true;
                console.log('Im in success');
            },
            error: function (res) {
                status = false;
            }
        });
    }

    console.log(status);
    return status;
}
```

In the output I get an "`Im in success`" and "`false`" which says that status is false. Why isn't it being set to true?

Comment: Ajax requests are `asyn` in nature hence you can not expect return values from them, use `callbacks` or `promise`

Comment: I added async: fasle, and it worked. Is that bad?

Comment: @DesirePRG That is not a good idea at all. Your screen freeze until request complete